# Can't save mongoose model with a reference to another object

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am trying to save a model that has a relationship to another one:

```
exports.portfolioSchema = new Schema({
    name: {type: String, required: true, unique: true},
    isActive: {type: Boolean, default: true}
});

exports.projectSchema = new Schema({
    name: {type: String, required: true, unique: true},
    isActive: {type: Boolean, required: true, default: true},
    portfolio: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'portfolioSchema', required: true},
    isCodeBaseFullyOwned: {type: Boolean, required: true, default: false}
});
```

While trying to save it:

```
Project = store.model('Project', schema.projectSchema);
var p = new Project();
p.name = project;
Portfolio.findOne({"name":activePortoflios[0]}, '_id', function (err, data) {
    p.portfolio = data._id;
});
p.isActive = true;
p.save(function (err) {
    if (err) console.log(err);
});
```

I get the following error:

```
{ ValidationError: Project validation failed
    at MongooseError.ValidationError (/Users/sasha/PycharmProjects/P5N/node_modules/mongoose/lib/error/validation.js:23:11)
    at model.Document.invalidate (/Users/sasha/PycharmProjects/P5N/node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js:1524:32)
    at /Users/sasha/PycharmProjects/P5N/node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js:1399:17
    at validate (/Users/sasha/PycharmProjects/P5N/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schematype.js:706:7)
    at /Users/sasha/PycharmProjects/P5N/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schematype.js:743:9
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at ObjectId.SchemaType.doValidate (/Users/sasha/PycharmProjects/P5N/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schematype.js:711:19)
    at /Users/sasha/PycharmProjects/P5N/node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js:1397:9
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:67:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)
  errors: 
   { portfolio: 
      { ValidatorError: Path `portfolio` is required.
          at MongooseError.ValidatorError (/Users/sasha/PycharmProjects/P5N/node_modules/mongoose/lib/error/validator.js:24:11)
          at validate (/Users/sasha/PycharmProjects/P5N/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schematype.js:705:13)
          at /Users/sasha/PycharmProjects/P5N/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schematype.js:743:9
          at Array.forEach (native)
          at ObjectId.SchemaType.doValidate (/Users/sasha/PycharmProjects/P5N/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schematype.js:711:19)
          at /Users/sasha/PycharmProjects/P5N/node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js:1397:9
          at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:67:7)
          at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)
        message: 'Path `portfolio` is required.',
        name: 'ValidatorError',
        properties: [Object],
        kind: 'required',
        path: 'portfolio',
        value: undefined } },
  message: 'Project validation failed',
  name: 'ValidationError' }
```

Is there something I am missing? `data._id` yields type ObjectId, do I need to set anything else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`findOne`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html) is an asynchronous call. Hence, when you try to save it, the `findOne` callback was not returned. As the property `portfolio` is required, it did not pass the validation.

```
Project = store.model('Project', schema.projectSchema);
var p = new Project();
p.name = project;

Portfolio.findOne({ name: activePortoflios[0] }, '_id', function (err, data) {
    if (err) return handleError(err);
    p.portfolio = data._id;
    p.isActive = true;
    p.save(function (err) {
        if (err) console.log(err);
    });
});
```

Comment: Is there a way to do things synchronously without callbacks?

Comment: NodeJs was designed to work with callbacks. What makes you bothered? You could use [promises](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/promises.html) if you prefer the syntax. Using a synchronous function will result to hang your process.